# How to add thousand GeoPoints in my MapActivity

Tags: android, google-maps

I have my android app and I want to show on my MapActivity 5 000 GeoPoints.
For This I use the next code:

```
for(BusinessUnitMapModel model : DeviceClientApplication.getInstance().getBusinessUnitList()){
            GeoPoint point = new GeoPoint((int)(Double.parseDouble(model.getLatitude())*1E6),(int)(Double.parseDouble(model.getLongitude())*1E6));
            OverlayItem overlayItem = new OverlayItem(point, "", "");
            itemizedOverlay.addOverlay(overlayItem);
}
```

But my application crashes when I try to enter to MapActivity.

May be somebody know how to add thousand of GeoPoints?

Comment: Can you post the stack trace of the crash to get a better idea of what is happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figure out that solution is to create additional server side Service which send not more than 50 stores according to screen coordinates (top-right and left-bottom). So if user zoom-out or zoom-in the map view Android application will send new requests to server-side. Any way user can't to see all 5000  points on the screen and user dont need that.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely what you're getting is an out of memory exception because of the large number of overlays you're adding to the map. If that's the case you'll need to find a workaround. There are a lot of different threads on the internet about this (search for 'android mapactivity memory exception') for you to look at and get suggestions from. Here's one example:

http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=2181

Good luck!